# CVXPY PSD constraint not working

Tags: python, optimization, covariance-matrix, convex, constrained-optimization

I am using CVXPY to solve for a PSD matrix, example as follows:

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

w =  np.array([0.3 , 0.25, 0.1 , 0.35])
C = cp.Variable((4,4), PSD=True)
objective = cp.Maximize(cp.quad_form(w, C))

constraints = [cp.diag(C) == np.array([0.0144, 0.0400, 0.0100, 0.0036]),
               C[0,1] == 0, C[3,1] <= 0.009, C[3,1] >= -0.009,  C[2,0] >= 0.0034]

prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
result = prob.solve()
np.linalg.cholesky(C.value)
```

The problem is that the resulting C matrix is not PSD (contains a tiny negative eigvalue), despite its attribute being PSD=True, I ran the same exercise on Matlab and worked well, i.e., the resulting C matrix is indeed PSD. Has anyone ran into this issue? Is this a CVXPY bug?
An alternative is to reconstruct the matrix using only non-negative eigenvalues (set the tiny negative eigvalue to zero) via spectral decomposition but ideally this should be an unnecessary step

Comment: I'll let someone else who knows more about this give an answer, but just to commiserate I've also had issues with CVXPY and positive definiteness. If it's really a tiny eigenval, like < 1e-10 in magnitude, then you can probably just consider it numerical noise; do you expect solutions to be on the boundary of the PSD constraint (i.e. rank deficient)?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, the tiny small eigval  (-1.45679544e-06) is not as small as 1e-10 but seems small enough to be numerical noise, I am curious why cvx in matlab handles it better (more precision).